# format data exported in excel from crystal report

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have designed a crystal report(ver. 13) in visual studio 2010 which works fine. it has a built in option for exporting the report into the excel file which it works fine too. But here is my question how can i control the format of the data in excel file, for example there are some cells which are empty or merged. how can in format the data appearance in excel file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the format. You have choice between export to excel with format and export data only (without format)

Comment: by exorting to "Excel" or "Excel data only". These are 2 diferent export types